# Reordering Google Sheet worksheets by date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets workbook with multiple sheets named by date. I am attempting to use a Google Apps Script to 1) reorder these sheets in reverse chronological order, and 2) to then move any future-dated sheets to the end of the workbook, so the first sheet is always the one with the most recent past date.

Step 1 works fine with the following code:

```
function sortGoogleSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Store all the worksheets in this array
  var sheetNameArray = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i].getName());
  }

  sheetNameArray.sort().reverse();

  // Reorder the sheets.
  for( var j = 0; j < sheets.length; j++ ) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[j]));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(j + 1);
  }
}
```

But step 2 does not work to then move the future-dated sheets to the end. There is no error generated, but the sheet order does not change. 'FutureSheetIDs' is a single-column named range containing the sheet IDs (e.g. 938739529, 532578283, etc.) of the sheets with dates > today, i.e. to be moved to the end of the workbook.

```
function resortFutureSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pos = ss.getNumSheets();
  var FutureSheets = ss.getRangeByName("FutureSheetIDs");
  for(var s=0 ; s < FutureSheets.length ; s++){
    var sh = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByID(FutureSheets[s]));
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(200);
    ss.moveActiveSheet(pos);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(200);
  }
}
```

Any guidance on why step 2 does not work as expected would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly 'doesn't work'? The script fails with an error as indicated with a red bar at the top of the screen? The script runs fine and some sheets move but not all sheets move as you expected?

Comment: Sorry, no, there is no error generated and the script completes, but it has no impact on the order of the sheets - none move as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets), incorporated into Apps Script as [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets.).

You can retrieve and modify the **sheet ID** and a **sheet index**, whereby as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets):

> The index of the sheet within the spreadsheet. When adding or updating
>   sheet properties, if this field is excluded then the sheet is added or
>   moved to the end of the sheet list. When updating sheet indices or
>   inserting sheets, movement is considered in "before the move" indexes.
>   For example, if there were 3 sheets (S1, S2, S3) in order to move S1
>   ahead of S2 the index would have to be set to 2. A sheet index update
>   request is ignored if the requested index is identical to the sheets
>   current index or if the requested new index is equal to the current
>   sheet index + 1.

Thus, for your request it would be useful to modify the index of the sheet, which you can do with

After [enabling](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) the Advanced Sheets Service, you can change the index( = position) of a sheet as following:

```
function myFunction() { 
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var FutureSheets=ss.getRangeByName("FutureSheets"); 
 var FutureIds=FutureSheets.getValues();
 var spreadsheetId=ss.getId();
 var sheets=ss.getSheets();
 for(s=0;s<FutureIds.length;s++)  { 
    if(FutureIds[s][0]==0){
      break;
    }else{
      var resource = {
        "requests": [
          {
            "updateSheetProperties": {
              "fields": "index",
              "properties": {
              "sheetId": FutureIds[s][0],
              "index": sheets.length
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works brilliantly. Except... because the named range (FutureSheets) contains many blank cells below those being filtered (to cope with the number of sheet IDs being filtered changing dynamically), when it hits the first blank value in the array the script technically fails even though everything has been re-ordered by that point. Any way to stop it throwing this error? `API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_sheet_properties.properties.sheet_id.value' (TYPE_INT32), "" `

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to implement it. For example, you can incorporate inside the `for` loop an if statement to check if the row is empty, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the values of the sheet IDs.

```
  var FutureSheets = ss.getRangeByName("FutureSheetIDs").getValues();
```

Also, note that `.getSheetByID('')` does not exist. You'll have to do a second loop and select the sheets by name based on their ID.

Also, I did something similar before and had issues with the sheets not actually updating their position if there is a large number of sheets. This seems to be due to a chasing issue and `.flush()` didn't have an impact. The sheet would have to be refreshed using F5

[Script to rename & reorder sheets based on table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237026/script-to-rename-reorder-sheets-based-on-table)

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working using .getSheetByName() and by adding an extra var to apply .getValues to, but it does seem very temperamental and only sometimes has an impact on the sheet order.

Comment: When it doesn't work, try to refresh once or twice using F5. If the sheet order changes as you expect it to after refreshing then you are encountering the cashing problem I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the best working solution, though it is quite temperamental:

```
  function resortFutureSheets(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pos = ss.getNumSheets();
  var FutureSheets = ss.getRangeByName("FutureSheetNames");
  var FutureSheetsArray = FutureSheets.getValues();
  for(var s = 0 ; s < FutureSheets.length; s++) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(FutureSheetsArray[s]));
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(200);
    ss.moveActiveSheet(pos);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(200);
  }
}
```